# Create table AspNetClaims in AspNetCore MVC Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identity

good night.
A curiosity...
I know it is possible to add columns to the identity tables, but is it possible to create other tables that will be related to the identity tables? Has anyone done?

Current scenario: when migration is applied, one of the tables that identity creates is AspNetRoles, which in turn has a 1 X N relationship to the AspNetRoleClaims table.

Realize that the identity does not have a single and exclusive table for Claims.

The intention is to create an AspNetClaims table in which all Claims will be registered. And I would take advantage of the AspNetRoleClaims table to have a relationship between the AspNetRoles tables and AspNetClaims.

The relationship would look like this:
AspNetRoles 1 X N AspNetRoleClaims 1 X N AspNetClaims

It's possible?
Does anyone have the implementation of something like that?

Comment: See the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-5.0#add-all-navigation-properties).It has a very detailed explanation.

Comment: What does it mean for one `AspNetRoleClaim` to have multiple `AspNetClaims`? And why not use the standard `AspNetUserClaims`? What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: @Xerillio, Hi
If you repair the solution that Identity gives us, we realize that the following relationship exists:AspNetRoles 1 X N AspNetRoleClaims
Since I’m creating a unique table to store claims information, I just want to supplement
the relationship with the AspNetRoleClaims table, which will look like this: AspNetRoles 1 X N AspNetRoleClaims 1 X N AspNetClaims
I don't want to do it on the AspNetUserClaim table because the main focus is the relationship with the AspNetRoleClaims table.

Comment: @BrunoQuintella but again: What problem are you actually trying to solve? I think the problem here is that you're not realizing what a role is and what a claim is (saying you are trying to "repair the solution that Identity gives us" indicates you are missing the point). Please read up on the difference between the two and try to focus your question on what it is you are trying to solve rather than explaining the attempt you are having trouble making work.

Comment: @Xerillio
Hi...
I will try to explain one more time.
Does Identity have a solution for registering users? Yes !! Does Identity have a solution to register a role? Yes!! But Identity has a solution to register a claim ??? No, there isn't !!!
Identity has the claim relationship with the user, but does not have an exclusive table for claims.

Comment: @BrunoQuintella despite your aggressive tone you still haven't explained why you need a claim that's not associated with either a user or role - that doesn't make sense to me. I'm sorry for my ignorance but I'm only trying to help you. Perhaps reading what an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) is will help you understand the problem here

Comment: @Xerillio
Sorry if the tone of my words is aggressive. At no time did I want to offend him with words. I am not that kind of person. The google translator doesn't help much either.
But back to the subject ... I'm just wanting to create an AspNetClaims table as an exclusive table for Claims, and relate it to the AspNetRoleClaims table. This way, I would have an exclusive table to register all my Claims, and I can still make a 1 x N relation with the AspNetRoleClaims table.